# Joining a specific IPv6 link-local multicast address

Tags: networking, ipv6, multicast

I think my issue comes from a lack of understanding exactly how the IPv6 multicast actually works but I had a hard time following the articles I found online.

The issue I'm trying to solve is how to configure a machine's network to join the specific IPv6 multicast address "ff02::1:e000:0700"

My IPv6 link address is "fe80::204:5fff:fea7:c84b" for reference.

So using another machine on the net, I can ping ff02::1 for instance and see my ip in the list of DUP responses as expected. I'm trying to understand what aspect I would need to configure to allow it to respond if I pinged the ff02::1:e000:0700 address.

I'm a novice with networking and am learning as I go. I appreciate any help or insight. Thanks!

Comment: You do not join a solicited-node multicast group, a host will automatically join a solicited-node multicast group based on a configured address. Also, `ff02::1:e000:0700` is _not_ a solicited-node multicast address; it is an undefined, well-known, link-local multicast address that should not be used. You can set the "T" flag to use it, but the flag is clear.

Comment: Oh, I was under the false impression then that anything ff02 was solicited-node multicast. So it's a link-local multicast address I'm trying to join then. I tried finding it online just now, but could you explain how I could set the "T" flag you're referring to?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The first flag set is the third hexadecimal digit, and the transient flag is the low-order bit. That would make what you want `ff12::1:e000:0700`. You need your application to join that multicast group to receive packets destined to that multicast group. Your sending application needs to send packets to that destination address.