# vsomeip-library - different behavior between IPv4 and IPv6 when using service discovery

Tags: linux, ipv6, vsomeip

### Setup:

- vsomeip 3.3.8
- Two Xenomai machines (Debian 11) connected via network switch
- "Mirrored services" on the two devices. Service 4433.2211 is offered and service 1234.5678 is requested on node 1. Node 2 does the opposite.

### Observations:

- Running the applications with IPv4 addresses creates the expected behavior. The two applications exchange data.
- Running the same applications with IPv6 addresses AND deactivated service discovery AND hard coded IPv6 addresses of the respective clients runs successfully.**It shows that my machines are capable to communicate using IPv6**.
- **PROBLEM**: Using active service discovery (without hard coded unicast addresses of the services), there is no communication between the two applications (note: Wireshark shows the service discovery communication)

  - I noticed that Wireshark displays a ICMPv6 message where it says "Multicast Address Record Changed to exclude: ff0e::1". Which is something I do not understand, because I did not request to exclude the address.

### Question

**Does anyone know why the nodes do not communicate? Is there anything specific for IPv6 that I need to set?**

- In my opinion it should be somewhere outside the C++ application. It should be something related to my Xenomai network settings. Or the json configuration files

#### Appendix: json configuration files and log of node 1

My json file for **node 1**:

```
{
"unicast" : "4242::1",
"logging" :
{
"level" : "trace",
"console" : "true",
"file" : { "enable" : "true", "path" : "/usr/cppPlayground/requestResponse2DevicesIpv6/node1.log" },
"dlt" : "false"
},
"applications" :
[
{
"name" : "request-response",
"id" : "0x1"
}
],
"services" :
[
{
"service" : "0x4433",
"instance" : "0x2211",
"unreliable" : "30510"
}
],
"routing" : "request-response",
"service-discovery" :
{
"enable" : "true",
"multicast" : "ff0e::1",
"port" : "30490",
"protocol" : "udp",
"initial_delay_min" : "10",
"initial_delay_max" : "100",
"repetitions_base_delay" : "200",
"repetitions_max" : "10",
"ttl" : "3",
"cyclic_offer_delay" : "2000",
"request_response_delay" : "1500"
}
}
```

My json file for **node 2**:

```
{
"unicast" : "4242::2",
"logging" :
{
"level" : "trace",
"console" : "true",
"file" : { "enable" : "true", "path" : "/usr/CppPlayground/requestResponseMirrored2DevicesIpv6/node2.log" },
"dlt" : "false"
},
"applications" :
[
{
"name" : "request-response-mirrored",
"id" : "0x9"
}
],
"services" :
[
{
"service" : "0x1234",
"instance" : "0x5678",
"unreliable" : "30509"
}
],
"routing" : "request-response-mirrored",
"service-discovery" :
{
"enable" : "true",
"multicast" : "ff0e::1",
"port" : "30490",
"protocol" : "udp",
"initial_delay_min" : "10",
"initial_delay_max" : "100",
"repetitions_base_delay" : "200",
"repetitions_max" : "10",
"ttl" : "3",
"cyclic_offer_delay" : "2000",
"request_response_delay" : "1500"
}
}
```

The log file for **node 1** (started AFTER node 2):

```
2023-09-15 15:35:21.279421 [info] Using configuration file: "vsomeip-local_IPv6.json".
2023-09-15 15:35:21.281261 [info] Parsed vsomeip configuration in 2ms
2023-09-15 15:35:21.281666 [info] Configuration module loaded.
2023-09-15 15:35:21.282017 [info] Initializing vsomeip (3.3.8) application "request-response".
2023-09-15 15:35:21.282568 [info] Instantiating routing manager [Host].
2023-09-15 15:35:21.283269 [info] create_routing_root: Routing root @ /tmp/vsomeip-0
2023-09-15 15:35:21.283987 [info] Service Discovery enabled. Trying to load module.
2023-09-15 15:35:21.285998 [info] Service Discovery module loaded.
2023-09-15 15:35:21.286556 [info] Application(request-response, 0001) is initialized (11, 100).
2023-09-15 15:35:21.287161 [info] Starting vsomeip application "request-response" (0001) using 2 threads I/O nice 255
2023-09-15 15:35:21.287993 [info] Client [0001] routes unicast:4242::1, prefix:24
2023-09-15 15:35:21.287908 [info] main dispatch thread id from application: 0001 (request-response) is: 7f6d7edde700 TID: 1378
2023-09-15 15:35:21.288016 [info] shutdown thread id from application: 0001 (request-response) is: 7f6d7e5dd700 TID: 1379
2023-09-15 15:35:21.289400 [info] Watchdog is disabled!
2023-09-15 15:35:21.290087 [info] REQUEST(0001): [1234.5678:255.4294967295]
2023-09-15 15:35:21.290180 [info] io thread id from application: 0001 (request-response) is: 7f6d7d5db700 TID: 1381
2023-09-15 15:35:21.290169 [info] io thread id from application: 0001 (request-response) is: 7f6d7fedcec0 TID: 1375
2023-09-15 15:35:21.290694 [info] create_local_server: Listening @ /tmp/vsomeip-1
2023-09-15 15:35:21.292821 [info] OFFER(0001): [4433.2211:0.0] (true)
2023-09-15 15:35:21.293393 [info] vSomeIP 3.3.8 | (default)
2023-09-15 15:35:21.293815 [info] Network interface "eno1" state changed: up
2023-09-15 15:35:21.294766 [info] Route "ff00::/8 if: eno1 gw: n/a" state changed: up
2023-09-15 15:35:21.295200 [info] udp_server_endpoint_impl: SO_RCVBUF is: 212992 (1703936) local port:30490
2023-09-15 15:35:21.295432 [debug] **Joining to multicast group ff0e::1 from 4242::1**
2023-09-15 15:35:21.295805 [info] udp_server_endpoint_impl: SO_RCVBUF is: 212992 (1703936) local port:30510
2023-09-15 15:35:21.295976 [info] udp_server_endpoint_impl: SO_RCVBUF is: 212992 (1703936) local port:30490
2023-09-15 15:35:21.296000 [info] SOME/IP routing ready.
2023-09-15 15:35:22.293609 [info] OFFER(0001): [4433.2211:0.0] (true)
2023-09-15 15:35:22.294419 [warning] routing_manager_impl::handle_local_offer_service: Application: 0001 is offering: [4433.2211.0.0] offered previously by itself.
2023-09-15 15:35:23.294958 [info] OFFER(0001): [4433.2211:0.0] (true)
2023-09-15 15:35:23.295723 [warning] routing_manager_impl::handle_local_offer_service: Application: 0001 is offering: [4433.2211.0.0] offered previously by itself.
*[... all the same as the two messages before...]*
2023-09-15 15:35:29.039199 [info] STOP OFFER(0001): [4433.2211:0.0] (true)
2023-09-15 15:35:29.039906 [info] RELEASE(0001): [1234.5678]
2023-09-15 15:35:30.304243 [info] Stopping vsomeip application "request-response" (0001).
```

I did analogous steps for IPv6 as I performed for IPv4.

1. Route multicast address to the ethernet device: `sudo ip -6 route add ff0e::1 dev eno1`
2. Start the respective application on both nodes: `env VSOMIP_CONFIGURATION...`

This way, I was expecting the same behavior as with IPv4. Of course, I tried a lot of other stuff related to network configurations, but nothing to exciting differently than the mentioned approach.

Comment: Multicast is not routed the same way as unicast is routed. You use multicast routing with IGMP (IPv4) or MLD (IPv6) and something like PIM. You join a multicast group to start IGMP (IPv4) or MLD (IPv6).

Comment: @RonMaupin: I thought that this is something that the ethernet device is taking care of by itself. So I believed that "sudo ip -6 route add ff0e::1 dev eno1" is exactly trying to achieve what you mention. It is not that I know it is doing what you mentioned. I believed it.

Comment: @RonMaupin: I also noticed your comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68628250/joining-a-specific-ipv6-link-local-multicast-address. There you write about "solicited-node multicast group". My multicast group "ff0e::1" is NOT fixed! I can set it to almost anything I want to make the communication working. Any hints?

Comment: I made a research on MLD and IGMP. Turns out, that the manual of my network switch (Netgear GS116Ev2) mentions IGMP only. No MLD. So I need to investigate further whether my network switch supports MLD. Maybe this is the reason that prevents service discovery in IPv6.

Comment: So I used as switch that supports MLD, and there are no Wireshark entries at all with IPv6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in vsomeip 3.3.8. It does not support service discovery with IPv6. A pull-request was opened some time ago. Unfortunately, the github search did not highlight the [pull-request](https://github.com/COVESA/vsomeip/pull/462) when I searched for relevant keywords...